# Analysing data from multiple matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have created a function which produces 1000 different matrices simulating the ranking of football teams.

The 1000th matrix produced is as so:

```
, , 1000

      [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    4    9
[3,]    2   10
[4,]    7   14
[5,]    9   14
[6,]    3   15
[7,]    5   16
[8,]    8   16
[9,]    6   17
[10,]   12   17
[11,]   14   17
[12,]   10   19
[13,]   13   21
[14,]   16   22
[15,]   11   24
[16,]   15   24
```

The first column represents the team, each team has a different number, and they are ordered from last place to first place. The second column indicates the points attained in the league.

The function that produces these matrices is called 'RANK'

I want to construct a matrix that contains the probabilities of each of the 16 teams attaining each possible position in the league.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to create empirical probabilities of each team coming at each position in the league based on the 1000 league matrices you have? If that is correct you can use the `table` function. Already having them in order makes this significantly easier. If the teams are ranked in the order `16:1` then

```
table("teams" = dat[,1,], "rank" = rep(dim(dat)[1]:1, dim(dat)[3])
```

returns a table of the teams against the ranks which can be used to find the empirical probabilities for both margins or the full joint distribution. See my reproducible example below:

```
f = function(){
  # generate a random table of results to look 
  # like op question with 3 teams
  cbind(team = sample(1:3),
  points = sort(rpois(3,10))
  )
}
# full data generation
dat = array(0,c(3,2,1000))
for(i in 1:1000) dat[,,i] = f()

table("teams" = dat[,1,], "rank" = rep(3:1, dim(dat)[3]))

##      rank
## teams   1   2   3
##     1 325 325 350
##     2 366 312 322
##     3 309 363 328
```

Dividing by the column or row totals will give you the marginal distributions, dividing by the total sum will give you the joint distribution.